# Network programming using C++

Tags: c++

How can we do network programming in C++ similar to Remoting in .NET? Please help with any tutorials.

It would be fine if I know how to enable two computers to communicate in the form of sending and receiving messages using C++/C#.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out our [C++ Remoting framework](http://www.appinf.com/en/products/remoting.html). There's also a [screencast](http://developer.appinf.com/?p=151) showing how to use it.

This is probably the closest that you'll get to .NET Remoting in C++.

Answer (score 2):

For windows, you can check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/beginningtcp_cpp.aspx).
You could refer [Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) for Unix flavors.

Comment: Indeed.  Whatever kind of network communication you are using, it all comes down to bare sockets.

Comment: Naked sockets are temptingly affordable.. ;))

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not have any native networking libraries, so if you don't want to use OS specific calls, you are going to need to use a portability layer.

Two that come to mind are [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) and [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the [Poco C++](http://pocoproject.org/) libraries. Especially the [Net](http://pocoproject.org/docs/00100-GuidedTour.html#4) module.

Answer (score 1):

For a pure C++ solution (as your first sentence suggests) that's also really simple to use, checkout [RCF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/Rcf_Ipc_For_Cpp.aspx).

If you want to communicate between C# and C++ programs (as your second sentence suggests) you'll have to look elsewhere, sorry.